# windows App Store xaml, the property 'Focusable' was not found in type 'Button'

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5, blend

I am creating userControl for custom touch keypad, in which each numeric key has its button. Now I need to keep the focus on textbox when the button touched then send the key into the focused textbox.

I thought I could achieve this by using Focusable property of buttons to 'False'....

But when I try to add the Focusable property to false then I am getting this error: the property 'Focusable' was not found in type 'Button'

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the user does not have a keyboard attached then the Windows on-screen keyboard will automatically appears when the TextBox takes keyboard focus. That keyboard will work exactly how you describe. Why do you need to create your own keypad control?

Comment: I need horizontal keypad with only numeric keys, you are right on-screen keyboard automatically appears, but I don't want that because of more space I need on the screen.

Comment: If you take that approach you might be breaking Windows UX rules and your app could be rejected for it. Are you able to prevent the on-screen keyboard from being displayed over the top of your custom keypad?

Comment: Not exactly, I am just showing buttons toolbar at bottom, contians all buttons in horizontal direction... to make sure App gets more room to show controls.

Comment: If the textbox set to IsReadonly to true then it won't show the soft keyboard then I can use my buttons to set numeric keys in textbox.